# Node js pause while loop wait until functions inside get executed completely?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coding a post request which downloads all URL HTML,zips them and email it back. This all should happen in the backend. I am storing all the data in an array and extract the first element to start these operations.

- I have while loop inside which I am calling some functions. Each function gets executed at a certain time.
- I used async, await and promises to make sure they run one after the
  other.

  Coming to my problem.
- My while loop starts getting executed again before all the
  functions inside it are executed.

```
app.post('/?', async (req, res) => {
    var urls = req.query.urls
    var email = req.query.email;

    var new_stack = [urls, email]
    stack.push(new_stack)
    res.send("Mail sent")
    if (isFunctionRunning === false) { //initially it is false
        console.log(isFunctionRunning, stack.length)
        send_mails();
    }
});

const getGoogleIndexHTML = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, (err, res, body) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(body))
    })
}

const some_function_to_download = async (url) => {
    try {
        const a = url.split(".")
        let googleIndexHTML = await getGoogleIndexHTML(url)
        await fs.writeFile(directory + '/' + a[1] + '.html', googleIndexHTML, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err
        })
        console.log('File created.')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

const html_to_zip_file = async () => {
    await zipper.zip(directory, function (error, zipped) {
        if (!error) {
            zipped.compress();
            zipped.save('./package.zip', function (error) {
                if (!error) {
                    console.log("Saved successfully !");
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
}
const send_mails = async () => {
    while (stack.length > 0) {
        isFunctionRunning = true
        var a = stack.shift()
        var urls = a[0]
        var collection_urls = urls.split(",");
        var to_email = a[1]
        rimraf(directory, function () {
            console.log("done");
        });

        fs.mkdirSync(directory);
        for (url of collection_urls) {
            await some_function_to_download(url); // 5 sec per download
        }
        await html_to_zip_file() // takes 5 sec to zip
            .then(result => {
                transporter.sendMail(set_mail_options(to_email))  //2 sec to send mail
                    .then(result => {
                        console.log("Mail sent")
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
            console.log("reached")   // this is reached before zip is done and mail sent. I want to prevent this
    }
    isFunctionRunning = false
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `some_function_to_download` and `html_to_zip_file()` is properly returning a promise?

Comment: You are not returning anything from `html_to_zip_file` as promise. Then if `transporter.sendMail` is also a promise you should `await` that as well.

Comment: it seems like you're just kinda throwing the async/await keywords around randomly.

Comment: No. I have written the code myself but for async-await, I have referred google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to return `transporter.sendMail` in `sendMail`, `fs.writeFile` in `someFunctionToDownload` and `zipper.zip` in `htmlToZipFile` otherwise the `await` won't work as expected (I'm assuming that they actually do return promises, I'm only familiar with `fs.writeFile`)
- Also: CamelCase is used in JS, not snake_case
- And are you sure `rimraf` is synchronous?

```js
const sendMails = async () => {
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    isFunctionRunning = true;
    const [urls, toEmail] = stack.shift();
    var collectionUrls = urls.split(",");

    rimraf(directory, function() {
      console.log("done");
    });

    await fs.mkdir(directory);

    await Promise.All(collectionUrls.map(someFunctionToDownload)); // 5 sec per download

    await htmlToZipFile() // takes 5 sec to zip
      .then(result => transporter.sendMail(set_mail_options(toEmail))) //2 sec to send mail
      .then(result => {
        console.log("Mail sent");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    console.log("reached"); // this is reached before zip is done and mail sent. I want to prevent this
  }
  isFunctionRunning = false;
};

const someFunctionToDownload = async url => {
  const a = url.split(".");
  const googleIndexHTML = await getGoogleIndexHTML(url);
  return fs.writeFile(`${directory}/${a[1]}.html`, googleIndexHTML, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
};

const htmlToZipFile = async () => {
  return zipper.zip(directory, function(error, zipped) {
    if (!error) {
      zipped.compress();
      zipped.save("./package.zip", function(error) {
        if (!error) {
          console.log("Saved successfully!");
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: 1. actually it is not, because (unfortunately, even though it's anti pattern), promises are not being chained here, so return has no value here.
2. `CamelCase is used in JS, not snake_case` what do you mean? there is no standard practice where naming are done in camelcase.

Comment: Yes there is ...
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--camelCase
https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-method-names

Comment: Yes they are style guides. Not standards.. :-) There are no standards there are style guides like airbnb ones, for readability.

Comment: The name tells `JavaScript Standard Style`, note the `STYLE` portion. Also, I know good amount of companies follow the 4 space tab style, and that's their style. Not standard. Also, logically tell me one thing, there are guides about spaces after if clause, is it because the code will fail? or improve readability. I am talking about that, no doubt camelcase is widely used, but you cannot say `camelcase is used in JS`, you can use whatever the heck you want in JS. (obviously that will have poor readibility). I hope you got my point.

Comment: This worked. Will focus more on learning promises and async/await.Thanks

Comment: @DhruvSingh Great! Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
while (stack.length > 0) {
    isFunctionRunning = true
    var a = stack.shift()
    var urls = a[0]
    var collection_urls = urls.split(",");
    var to_email = a[1]
    rimraf(directory, function () {
        console.log("done");
    });

    fs.mkdirSync(directory);
    for (url of collection_urls) {
        await some_function_to_download(url); // 5 sec per download
    }
    try {
       const result = await html_to_zip_file() // takes 5 sec to zip
       const sendMailResult = await transporter.sendMail(set_mail_options(to_email))
    } catch(e) 
      {
       console.log(e)
      }

    console.log("reached") 
}
```

Since html_to_zip_file() and sendMail function are independent
we can use

```
const result = await Promise.all([html_to_zip_file(),transporter.sendMail(set_mail_options(to_email))]);
```